# postgresql query performance issue with timestamp and order by filter

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have table definition as following.

```
CREATE TABLE monmgr_pg.order_staged_events (
  event_id varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  order_number varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  oms_order_key varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  event_name varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  event_timestamp timestamp DEFAULT NOW(),
  order_type varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  event_dto text NOT NULL,
  sequence_number NUMERIC(3,0) NOT NULL,
  sub_sequence_number NUMERIC(3,0) NOT NULL,
  "version" NUMERIC(38,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  error_code varchar(35) NULL,
  processed_count  NUMERIC(38,0) DEFAULT 0,
  create_timestamp timestamp DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

I am  firing following query on this table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OMS_ORDER_KEY 
FROM ( 
   SELECT OMS_ORDER_KEY 
   FROM ORDER_STAGED_EVENTS 
   WHERE SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 101  
    AND SUB_SEQUENCE_NUMBER IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
    AND EVENT_TIMESTAMP > (now()-INTERVAL '12 hours') 
    AND PROCESSED_COUNT <= 4 
    ORDER BY EVENT_TIMESTAMP ASC 
    FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS only
) X;
```

This table will have 4-5 million records for last 12 hours and total entries in table might cross 20-30 million.I have tried to create different combination of indexes like combined index on (sequence_number, sub_sequence_number, event_timestamp) and separate indexes on columns but still query execution time is reaching up-to 20-30 seconds when no of records increases.processed_count column value is updated after successful processing.

Can someone please help me deciding correct indexes on this table to improve query performance.

Comment: How many rows do you have per `sequence_number`?  If that condition reduces the number of rows substantially, I would probably try an index on `(sequence_number, event_timestamp)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually we have partition on sequence_no and each seq_no partition can have 2-3 million records for last 12 hours.

Comment: Then please show us the **complete** table definition including the partitioning information. Also what is your Postgres version? The query as shown should already pick the correct partition. In that case try an index on `(event_timestamp, processed_count)`  or `(processed_count, event_timestamp)` depending on which condition is more restrictive.

Comment: As partitioning is involved: which Postgres version are you using? (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using postgresql 11.4, yes query will pick correct partition.after reaching partition we have to filter records. processed_count column we update after processing of row so will it be correct candidate for indexing as index tree has to be rebuilt after update happens.

Comment: As I said: try an index on `(event_timestamp, processed_count)` or `(processed_count, event_timestamp)`

Comment: Actually, an index on `event_timestamp` alone might be the best. This query could not use more than the first column of an index, and this way you may get a fast plan because of the `LIMIT 10000`.

Comment: Try this query. CREATE INDEX Index_Name_1 ON order_staged_events(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,EVENT_TIMESTAMP ASC,PROCESSED_COUNT)
CREATE INDEX Index_Name_2 ON order_staged_events(SUB_SEQUENCE_NUMBER)


SELECT DISTINCT
  OMS_ORDER_KEY
FROM
   ORDER_STAGED_EVENTS O
INNER JOIN unnest(string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5,6', ',')) A(Val)
ON   O.SUB_SEQUENCE_NUMBER=A.Val
WHERE
  SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 101  
  AND EVENT_TIMESTAMP > (now()-INTERVAL '12 hours') 
  AND PROCESSED_COUNT <= 4
ORDER BY EVENT_TIMESTAMP ASC 
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS only

Comment: are they any variables in that query or is it always the same?  a partial index may be the solution.

Comment: Does the Execution Plan and/or execution time change [radically] if you remove the "distinct" clause?